# blazor - does stathaschanged() on app-layout changes everything in body?

Tags: blazor

I want a system time in the main layout on top, but this changes only in the chadow DOM. To make it visible I need to use StateHaschanged().
My issue is, the main layout has the whole body of the website in it, does it re-render it too? If yes, it would lead to a performance issue...

Does StateHasChanged() in main AppLayout changes the whole body in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cause what is called a "Render Cascade" down the Render tree.  Any child with a `Parameter` reference object will have it's `SetParmetersAsync` called even if it hasn't changed.  As you're almost certainly using `ComponentBase` this will trigger a render.  And any grandchild .......  Note that `ChildContent` is a `RenderFragment` and thus a reference object.

The simple way to solve your problem is to encapsulate the time display in a component which you then place in the layout.  `TimeDisplayComponent` is now a child of `AppLayout` and doesn't trigger a render event in the parent.  "Render Cascades" only propagate down the tree not up.